# how to translate drupal menu minipanels?

Tags: drupal, internationalization, drupal-panels

I have a Druapl 7 website which heavily uses menu minipanels.  Now this site is being translated into additional languages and I struggle to make the menupanels appear under the new translated menu items.
Has any one tackled this task and been successful?